# Change final variable defined in another java file

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm programming a mod.

Here's the code:

```
package net.minecraft.client.gui;

import java.io.IOException;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.audio.PositionedSoundRecord;
import net.minecraft.client.audio.SoundHandler;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GlStateManager;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class GuiButton extends Gui {
    public static final ResourceLocation buttonTextures = new ResourceLocation("textures/gui/widgets.png");
```

As you can see, there's the variable `buttonTextures` and its resource location is *"textures/gui/widgets.png"*. And I also have a second one and what I want to do is to change the `buttonTextures` with this second Java file when I execute it.
I just need to change the resource location of `buttonTextures` to my own path, but by an other Java file. Maybe it can be done by re-writing the code with the second script, I really have no clue.

**What I'm making:**
A PAYDAY 2 Mod for Minecraft. And of course, I'm starting with the menu. So I have two main menus. To switch to my menu, there's a button which you have to press. When you do that, it changes its texture. But the problem is, that it can't change the button textures to *textures/gui/PAYDAY2widgets.png*, because the variable is `final`.

As you can see, the first file is called `GuiButton`.
I made a copy of that file, called it `GuiPAYDAY2Button.java`, and set the path to my path to the texture (*textures/gui/PAYDAY2widgets.png*).
Now if I add that to the | (I changed the variables from `GuiButton` to `GuiPAYDAY2Button`, but then the game crashes after switching to the *PAYDAY2* menu) | `GuiPAYDAY2MainMenu.java` file (the copy of the `GuiMainMenu.java`file).
I also changed `GuiButton` to `GuiPAYDAY2Button`(in the `GuiPAYDAY2MainMenu.java` file), so it's directed to that file.
As I was talking about the crashing, this is the crash-report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ---- // I feel sad now :(

Time: 8.4.15 21:58 Description: Rendering screen

java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiPAYDAY2Button cannot be cast to net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiButton
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.drawScreen(GuiScreen.java:99)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiPAYDAY2MainMenu.drawScreen(GuiPAYDAY2MainMenu.java:453)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.updateCameraAndRender(EntityRenderer.java:1167)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1127)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:410)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:114)
    at Start.main(Start.java:11)
```

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.drawScreen(GuiScreen.java:99)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiPAYDAY2MainMenu.drawScreen(GuiPAYDAY2MainMenu.java:453)

-- Screen render details --
Details:
    Screen name: net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiPAYDAY2MainMenu
    Mouse location: Scaled: (202, 11). Absolute: (405, 456)
    Screen size: Scaled: (427, 240). Absolute: (854, 480). Scale factor of 2
    Stacktrace:
        at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.updateCameraAndRender(EntityRenderer.java:1167)
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1127)
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:410)
        at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:114)
        at Start.main(Start.java:11)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.8.0_31, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 707532608 bytes (674 MB) / 1038876672 bytes (990 MB) up to 1038876672 bytes (990 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: mcp
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: GeForce GTX 460 v2/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.5.0 NVIDIA 347.25, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing. Using GL 1.3 texture combiners. Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported. Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported. VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.
    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Very likely; Jar signature invalidated
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

### UPDATE

I made a video some hours ago and it's a showcase to this mod. Maybe you'll understand what I want..: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocHT7LdNBYY

Ok, I made the extending script look like this:

```
package net.minecraft.client.gui; 
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation; 

public class GuiButtonTexureChange extends GuiButton { 
    public static ResourceLocation buttonTextures = new ResourceLocation("textures/gui/PAYDAY2widgets.png");

    // Now this part is needed to be here (otherwise it throws errors):
    public GuiButtonTexureChange(int buttonId, int x, int y, int widthIn, int heightIn, String buttonText) { 
        super(buttonId, x, y, widthIn, heightIn, buttonText); // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is a final variable, and the `ResourceLocation` class is immutable. You are out of luck - you can't replace it, and you can't change its content, except by changing the code of the class where it is defined.

Comment: Why not just put your texture file at textures/gui/widgets.png?

Comment: because I don't want to have the PAYDAY2 button textures in the main menu ;).

Comment: Can't you make a class that *extends* GuiButton, but overrides the texture file? I remember doing that in the past, and it has always worked.

Comment: ok, I know the code to extend the file, but how do I execute the extending java file through the GuiPAYDAY2MainMenu?(want the code to execute the extending script..)

Comment: `final` means it is readonly, so you cannot set a new value. Unless you would do some advanced JVM hacking.

Comment: You are going to have to extend the required classes, then implement your own menu with the buttons. You aren't going to be able to change variables declared as final.

Comment: I can still change it to "public static" instead of "public static final" right?

Comment: ok, I made the extending script look lke this:

`package net.minecraft.client.gui;

import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class GuiButtonTexureChange extends GuiButton {

 public static ResourceLocation buttonTextures = new ResourceLocation("textures/gui/PAYDAY2widgets.png");

// Now this part is needed to be here (otherwise it throws errors):

 public GuiButtonTexureChange(int buttonId, int x, int y, int widthIn,
   int heightIn, String buttonText) {
  super(buttonId, x, y, widthIn, heightIn, buttonText);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
}
`
@EvanBechtol

Comment: @TomLenc I added the snippet you just posted as an update to your post. Please do this in the future. Your comment is near unreadable like that!

Comment: @TomLenc Why do you merge your first update with the second one? Is there any logic behind that?

Comment: @Tom I'm not merging it. The users are editing it..

Comment: You're not merging it? So where is Update *1* in your post? An Update No. 2 makes no sense if there is no No. 1.

Comment: cuz it was No. 1 before ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify some Java code (for instance it is part of a library), you can still overwrite any Java class you like.

Create another source folder (speaking in terms of Eclipse here), and inside that the exact package and file as the class you want to edit. In your case it should be package **net.minecraft.client.gui** and file **GuiButton.java**.

Now, if your own file comes first in classpath, you have successfully overwritten a class. All the other code of the library still works as it used to.

To ensure that your own code comes first in classpath when working with Eclipse:
*Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export*

It is probably wise to copy the existing code (of GuiButton) into your own file to have the same starting point, and then do your modifications on the code.

Comment: And that code under the UPDATE is not mine..
That means that i don't know how to execute the script in another script..
I'm really s**tty beginner :D

Comment: I have all the files that were mentioned in the same package (net.minecraft.gui)..
But how do I execute this script by script? :D I mean what is the code to execute them?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your security manager settings, you could change the path string at runtime via reflection.

Example :

```
static void setFinalStatic(final Field field, final Object instance, final Object newValue) throws Exception {
      field.setAccessible(true);

      final Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
      modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
      modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL & ~Modifier.PRIVATE);
      field.set(instance, newValue);
}

public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String path = "initialPath";
      final char[] after = "sneakyPath".toCharArray();
      setFinalStatic(path.getClass().getDeclaredField("value"), path, after);
      setFinalStatic(path.getClass().getDeclaredField("offset"), path, 0);
      setFinalStatic(path.getClass().getDeclaredField("count"), path, after.length);

      System.out.println(path);
}
```